# Adding/removing input fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pretty new to ReactJS, I'm liking it a lot, but there are some things like binding that seems to be easier in Angular.

I want to have a form, where a user can click a button to add extra input fields. At any point, they can also "delete" an input field.

On the submit, I want to get these inputs as an array, i.e. pass `dynamicInputs` to my API which contains an array of `name`.

This is what I've done (which is probably wrong since I'm treating React like Angular):

```
var React = require('react');

module.exports = React.createClass({
    addInputField: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var inputs = this.state.inputs;
        inputs.push({name: null});
        this.setState({inputs : inputs});
    },
    removeInputField: function(index) {
        var inputs = this.state.inputs;
        inputs.splice(index, 1);
        this.setState({inputs : inputs});
    },
    handleSubmit: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // What do I do here?
    },
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {inputs : []};
    },
    render: function (){
        var inputs = this.state.inputs;
        return (
            // Setting up the form
            // Blah blah
           <div className="form-group">
               <label className="col-sm-3 control-label">Dynamic Inputs</label>
               <div className="col-sm-4">
                   {inputs.map(function (input, index) {
                       var ref = "input_" + index;
                       return (
                           <div className="input-group">
                                <input type="text" className="form-control margin-bottom-12px" placeholder="Enter guid" value={input.name} ref={ref} aria-describedby={ref} />
                                <span className="input-group-addon" onClick={this.removeInputField.bind(this, index)} id={ref} ><i className="fa fa-times"></i></span>
                           </div>
                       )
                   }.bind(this))}
                    <button className="btn btn-success btn-block" onClick={this.addInputField}>Add Input</button>
               </div>
           </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Right now `removeInputField` does NOT work! It just removes the last entry all the time.

Comment: Have you checked the console? It should state you must have a `key` for your `<div className="input-group">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `<div className="input-group">` must have a unique key

```
<div className="input-group" key={index}>
```

That's how React distinguishes between collection of rendered nodes.

References:

- https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children

**UPD**:

As @WiredPrairie mentioned below in the comments - the suggested solution is far from ideal, since the `index` is not unique enough. And instead you need to create another array with some unique identifiers (a monotonously growing sequence would be enough) and maintain it in parallel with `this.state.inputs` and use its values as keys.

So, on adding an element you:

```
this.keys.push(++this.counter);
```

on removing - remove from both by the same `index`. And in the `.map` you

```
<div className="input-group" key={this.keys[index]}>
```

Comment: Using `index` can lead to problems though when dealing with an array where items are removed/added.

Comment: @WiredPrairie that's a valid point. Then OP needs to maintain an array of unique values separately.

Comment: @WiredPrairie added a fix :-)

Comment: @zerkms now i am not have enough knowledge to apply your answer could you please elaborate it, because i am also have this same issue